# Is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ with the usual addition and scalar multiplication a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In checking distributivity I became confused. I'm supposed to check that $(a+b)v = av + bv$, but suppose $a=3, b=4$. $a+b\equiv2\mod{5}$ and $2\not=7$. Can someone clarify what happens here?

Comment: I think you mean a vector space, not a vector field?

Comment: @joriki Certainly, sorry and thank you hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that $\Bbb R^n$ fails to be a vector space over $\Bbb Z_5$. For any vector space over $\Bbb Z_5$, any vector $v$ must obey $$5v=v+v+v+v+v=0$$which also leads to $2v=7v$. And that just isn't true in $\Bbb R^n$ with standard vector addition, as you have discovered.

Comment: How are you defining scalar multiplication?

Comment: @joriki As long as the scalars are multiplies of $1$, by the axioms: $1v=v$ plus distribution.

Comment: I see – so by "$\mathbb R^n$ fails to be a vector space over $\mathbb Z_5$", you mean something like "If you assume that a structure $(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb Z_5,+,\cdot)$ satisfies the vector space axioms, you can derive a contradiction." I'd read it more like "$(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb Z_5,+,\cdot)$ with certain implied operations $+$ and $\cdot$ doesn't satisfy the vector space axioms" (as one would read it e.g. in "The solutions of $x^n=1$ fail to be a vector space over $\mathbb C$.") and was wondering which operations were implied.

Comment: But wait, you did refer to standard vector addition. So your argument is actually a mix of both -- you're assuming that $+$ is standard vector addition and showing that there's then no way to define $\cdot$ such that the axioms are satisfied?

Comment: I think that would be more clearly described as "We cannot turn $\mathbb R^n$ into a vector space over $\mathbb Z_5$".

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as “$\mathbb{R}^{n}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ with the usual addition and scalar multiplication”. You may be thinking of the usual scalar multiplication for $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb Z$, with $(n\cdot v)_i=n\cdot v_i$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, $v\in\mathbb R^n$, but this doesn’t define a scalar multiplication for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, since that would require multiplying $n\in\mathbb Z_5$ by $v_i\in\mathbb R$, and multiplication of elements of $\mathbb Z_5$ and elements of $\mathbb R$ is not defined.